# Finding Median and average of list in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am having trouble finding a way to calculate the median and average of a list of numbers and the resources online seem to be really limited with Tcl. So far I managed to only print the numbers of the list.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
proc ladd {l} {
    set total 0
    set counter 0
    foreach nxt $l {
        incr total $nxt
        incr counter 1
    }
    puts "$total"
    puts "$counter"

    set average ($total/$counter)

    puts "$average"


}

set a [list 4 3 2 1 15 6 29]
ladd $a
```

Comment: Is there only one element in a list? Is to goal the to get the median across all list elements or within each list?

Comment: *the resources online seem to be really limited with Tcl* really now?

Comment: The goal is to get the median across all elements within one list, so in my example the elements 4,3,2,1

Comment: Do you know how to get the median and the average using pen and paper?

Comment: The average would be (4+3+2+1)/4 which is 2.5 and the median would be the middle number. But I am having trouble converting that into tcl code.

Comment: Ok since you know how to calculate the average, how about you try to find out how to add numbers first?

Comment: [`math::statistics`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/math/statistics.md) from tcllib has commands for both. Though if this is an assignment you presumably can't use them.

Comment: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Summing+a+list will be useful reading.

Comment: You can use `lsort -integer $l` to get your list of integers sorted.  For the median, try the following: `set len [llength $sorted_list];` `set mid1 [expr ($len-1)/2];` `set mid2 [expr ($len-0)/2];` `set median [expr 0.5*([lindex $sorted_list $mid1]+[lindex $sorted_list $mid2])];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the average (i.e., the *arithmetic mean*) of a list, you can just do:

```
proc average {list} {
    expr {[tcl::mathop::+ {*}$list 0.0] / max(1, [llength $list])}
}
```

That sums the values in the list (the trailiing `0.0` forces the result to be a floating point value, even if all the added numbers are integers) and divides by the number of elements (or 1 if the list is empty so an empty list gets a mean of 0.0 instead of an error).

To get the median of a list, you have to sort it and pick the middle element.

```
proc median {list {mode -real}} {
    set list [lsort $mode $list]
    set len [llength $list]
    if {$len & 1} {
       # Odd number of elements, unique middle element
       return [lindex $list [expr {$len >> 1}]]
    } else {
       # Even number of elements, average the middle two
       return [average [lrange $list [expr {($len >> 1) - 1] [expr {$len >> 1}]]]
    }
}
```

To complete the set, here's how to get the mode of the list if there is a unique one (relevant for some applications where values are selected from a fairly small set):

```
proc mode {list} {
    # Compute a histogram
    foreach val $list {dict incr h $val}
    # Sort the histogram in descending order of frequency; type-puns the dict as a list
    set h [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -descending -integer $h]
    # The mode is now the first element
    return [lindex $h 0]
}
```

I'll leave handling the empty and non-unique cases as an exercise.